# VB2010 - For Loop Exiting Issue

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I have a simple for loop with the following code

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To 4
            Snake(i).X = (120 - 20 * i)
            Snake(i).Y = 120
            SnakeBody(i).Location = New Point(Snake(i).X, Snake(i).Y)
            Snake(i).Facing = 3
        Next i
```

But for some reason I unable to debug it. I place a breakpoint on the line `Snake(i).X = (120 - 20 * i)` and When I try to see what the values are the second time the loop iterates it simply exits the loop. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you stepping to a catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a breakpoint on the first line of the loop and step through it line by line.